# If G is a finite group, and $\exists !$ $H\leq G$ such that $|H| =n$, then $H \triangleleft G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

So far this is what I'm thinking:

Suppose the $G$ has exactly one subgroup of size $n$.

Let $N$ be a subgroup of $G$ of size $n$.

By Lagrange's Theorem we know $|N| \mid |G|$

But pretty much after that I'm a little confused about where to go and I'm not even sure I'm starting off correctly. I know to be a normal subgroup $N$ must be a subgroup of $G$ and if $a\in N$ and $b\in G$ then $b^{-1}ab\in N$. I do remember something that if $|N| = n,\;$ let $a\in G$ such that $N=\{a^{n}\mid a\in \mathbb{N}\}$ so $\,N\,$ is the subgroup generated by $\langle a \rangle,\,$ which means $\,O(a) \mid |G|\,$ and is possibly isomorphic to $\langle \mathbb{Z}_{o(a)},+,-,0\rangle$.

I'm really not sure and I'm pretty sure all I just said is wrong.

Comment: "$|N| \mid |G|$"… It's not quite as bad as $\Xi \over \bar\Xi$ (the notation that according to anecdote caused Serge Lang to burst out "your notation sucks!"), but it's still quite unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

A subgroup $H$ of $G$ is normal if $g^{-1}Hg=H$. Show that $g^{-1}Hg$ is always a subgroup of $G$ and that it has the same size as $H$ does. Conclude the result.

Comment: Your answer is basically the same as mine.

Comment: I was about to add the same comment to your answer :)

Comment: I think I answered 35 seconds earlier :)

Comment: So how exactly would I go about proving gNg^-1 is a subgroup of G? Like do I define N to be the group N={g|g is in G and x^-1gx is in H for all x in G}? Im sorry but I have an awful professor, we even had a sub the other day and he couldn't believe the things we haven't been taught.

Comment: To show that a set $S\subseteq G$ (such as $S=gHg^{-1}$) is a subgroup, you need to verify that $S$ contains the identity, and that $xy^{-1}\in S$ whenever $x,y\in S$.

Comment: So this is what I did for the subgroup: $1\in S$ since $g1g^{-1}=1$ for all $a\in N$ then suppose $a\in N$ then $gag^{-1} \in S$ so $(gag^{-1})^{-1} \in S$ so $ga^{-1}g^{-1} \in S$ and finally Suppose $a_{0},a_{1} \in N$ then $a_{0}a_{1}\in N$ so $ga_{0}a_{1}g^-1=ga_{0}g^{-1}ga_{1}g^{-1}$ and we know $ga_{0}g^{-1} \in S$ and $ga_{1}g^{-1} \in S$ and S is a subgroup of G.

Comment: @Gamecocks99, you may also note that for a fixed $g \in G$, the map $G \to G$ that sends $x \mapsto g x g^{-1}$ is a group homomorphism (actually an isomorphism), so it sends a subgroup to a subgroup.